# Classification, cross_val_score() returns an array of 1

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I have this pipeline, where `X_train` and `y_train` are both arrays are have the same number of rows (all integer and floats, y_train is binary, with values 1 and 0). When I run it, all seems to be going perfectly. This is the code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, KFold

seed = 7
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10)

pipe = Pipeline([
    ('Scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ("Imputer", KNNImputer()),
    ('ML', RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=3))])

results = cross_val_score(pipe, X_train, y_train, cv=kfold, scoring="roc_auc")
```

When I try to print the results, it gives me this:

```
print(results)
array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

It gives an array of 10 values of 1.

- Why?
- How can I access to those models each one?
- And how can I choose the best one (assuming they have different values)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained in the docs of the [`cross_val_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html) function.

In your example you obtain the ROC AUC on each of the folds (by the choice of your `scoring` parameter)

I guess your model is severely overfitting the data, that's what the AUC is always 1.0, i.e. the maximal value

Comment: Got it, but how can I access to those models in order to predict on X_test? Is there any way to select the best one? (assumming they aren't all ones)

Comment: This is a completely different questions. Typically, say in gaggle challenges, the cross val score gives you a performance estimate. Now, you, typically want to `fit` it on a portion or all of the training data. Once your estimator (i.e. your pipeline) is fitted, you can use the `predict` method to create predictions on different (e.g. test) data